# Why does using the following definition of $\sin(x)$ result in the wrong integral for $\int \sin(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, indefinite-integrals

Using the following definition of $\sin(x)$

$$\sin(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}\right)$$

Results in the following integral

$$\begin{align}
\int \sin(x)\ dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int\left(e^{ix} - e^{-ix}\right) \ dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right) + C
\end{align}$$

But $\int \sin(x)\ dx = -\cos(x) + C \iff \int \sin(x)\ dx = \frac{1}{2}\int\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right) + C$. Thus the $\frac{1}{i}$ multiplicand is the term here is what is producing the wrong integral.

Is it only possible to integrate $\sin(x)$ and prove $\int \sin(x) = -\cos(x) + C$ via the Taylor Series definition of $\sin(x)$?

$$\sin(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1} \ \ \ \ \ \text{(Taylor Series Definition)}$$

Comment: Your starting definition is missing $i$ at the denominator.

Comment: Hint: Your definition of the sine function is wrong, so is your antiderivative of $\sin (x)$.

Comment: Also, $\int\sin(x)dx$ is **not** $\cos(x) + C$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the usual mistake in mathematics: sloppyness!

> Using the following definition of $\sin(x)$
>
> $$\sin(x) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix} -
>  e^{-ix}\right)$$

**Wrong**. The formula you wrote evaluates to

$$\frac12(\cos x + i\sin x - (\cos(-x) + i\sin(-x))) = \frac12(\cos x + i\sin x - \cos x + i\sin x) =\frac12 (2i\sin x) = i\sin x \neq \sin x$$

---

Using the **correct** formula for $\sin x$ (which is $\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}$) will get you:

$$\int \sin x dx = \frac{1}{2i}\int(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})dx =\\
=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\int e^{ix} dx - \int e^{-ix} dx \right)=\\
=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{i}e^{ix} - \frac{1}{-i} e^{-ix}\right)+C=\\
=\frac{1}{2i}\cdot \frac{1}{i}\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix}\right)+C=\\
=\frac{1}{-2}(\cos x + i\sin x + \cos(-x) + i\sin(-x))+C=\\
=\frac{1}{-2}(\cos x + i\sin x + \cos(x) - i\sin(x))=\\
=\frac{1}{-2}\cdot2\cdot \cos x+C = -\cos x+C$$

Which works out to what you would expect.

Comment: I like "You made the usual mistake in mathematics: sloppyness!" :) +1

Answer (score 3):

> Notice, Euler's formula (and de Moivre formula):
>
> $$e^{\theta i}=\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i$$
>
> And use:
>
> - $$\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$$
> - $$\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$$

---

So, we get:

$$e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}=\left(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i\right)-\left(\cos(-\theta)+\sin(-\theta)i\right)=$$
$$\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i-\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i=2\sin(\theta)i$$

So:

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}{2i}$$

Now, the integral become:

$$\int\sin(\theta)\space\text{d}\theta=\int\frac{e^{\theta i}-e^{-\theta i}}{2i}\space\text{d}\theta=\frac{1}{2i}\left[\int e^{\theta i}\space\text{d}\theta-\int e^{-\theta i}\space\text{d}\theta\right]=$$
$$\frac{-ie^{\theta i}-ie^{-\theta i}}{2i}+\text{C}=\text{C}-\cos(\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

By the Euler and de Moivre formulas,

$$e^{ix}-e^{-ix}=(\cos x+i\sin x)-(\cos x-i\sin x)=2i\sin x.$$

---

Other check:

$$(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^2=e^{2ix}-2+e^{-i2x}=2\cos(2x)-2,$$ which is a negative number !

---

The developments of $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ differ in the sign of the terms of odd power, so that when you subtract them, only the odd powers remain, and $i^{2k+1}=\pm i$.

---

You can establish two integrals in a single go, as follows:

$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,$$ then omitting the constant,

$$\int e^{ix}dx=\frac{e^{ix}}i=\sin x-i\cos x.$$ Then equate the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: $2 \cos (2x)-2$ isn't always negative, it is *certainly* always non-positive though :-)

Comment: @Bacon: with $x$ uniformly spread in $[0,2\pi)$, the expression is almost certainly negative. :)